# variable value is not appending in h2 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, overlay

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/pc2tx1us/1/)

```
Hi, I have variable called "var node = "Hi Mr", Iam trying to append this value on click of a button, im  not sure why its not appending. 
I tried using html and text, none worked.
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.customerResultIndex').on('click',function(){
        openCustomerOverlay();
    })

});
function openCustomerOverlay(){
    var node = "Hi Mr"
    $('.customerPopHeading').text(node)

    var overlayContainer = 
    '<div class="customerOverlayShadow">'+
        '<div class="customerOverlay borderRadius10px">'+
            '<h2 class="customerPopHeading">-- </h2>'+
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the element first, them after this, set the text...
You are setting the text befero creating it.

Put this:

```
var node = "Hi Mr";
$('.customerPopHeading').text(node);
```

After this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {  
        $('.customerOverlayShadow').remove();   
    }
});
```

Final result:
http://jsfiddle.net/pc2tx1us/3/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append a value like this instead you can concatenate it this way:

```
'<h2 class="customerPopHeading">--'+ node +'</h2>'+
```

or you can move this line:

```
$('.customerPopHeading').text(node);
```

below this:

```
$("body").prepend(overlayContainer).focus();
$('.customerPopHeading').text(node);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc2tx1us/4/)

The element has to be available to make a jQuery selector, here when you prepend in body only then it is available to put the desired text in it.