# Not able to set value for Dynamic Dropdown in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a dynamic layout in which it has dropdown which is populated dynamically from websql I had to set a value for that dropdown when I come back to the page that has dropdown as I am removing that layout it is not persisiting value  I tried various ways but not able to do so instead I am getting blank value.the  value that I have to set as selected from value.

```
 ansSet = questions[i].Question.Answers.Answer;
     var fieldSerCntrl;
    fieldSerCntrl = '<div id="AnswerSection" class="Answerboldtext" style=" border-spacing: 2px; width:100%; margin-left:10px"><table style=" border-spacing: 1px; width:100%; margin-left:20px">' +
            '<tr style=" border-spacing: 1px; width:100%">' +
            '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="width:80%"><select name="select-choice" id='+questions[i].Question.QuestionId+' class="dropdown" style="width:100%">';
   fieldSerCntrl = fieldSerCntrl + '<option><h5>Select Option</h5></option>';
     for (ansCnt = 0; ansCnt < ansSet.length; ansCnt++) {
        fieldSerCntrl = fieldSerCntrl + '<option value='+ansCnt+'><h5>' + ansSet[ansCnt].Description + '</h5></option>';
     console.log("ansCnt"+ansCnt);
    // $('#'+questions[i].Question.QuestionId).val($('#'+questions[i].Question.QuestionId 'option').eq(3).val());
    }
    fieldSerCntrl = fieldSerCntrl + '</select></fieldset></tr></table></div>'

    $("#QuestionsDesc").append(fieldSerCntrl);

    // $("#"+questions[i].Question.QuestionId 'option[value='+check_back[i]+']').attr('selected', true);
```

I am new to jquery Could anyone suggest how to proceed.

Comment: can u plz post a fiddle

Comment: @undefined I had a layout that is created dynamically and values also I am getting dynamically.Could you suggest like this meanwhile will try to write in fiddle

Comment: u can save the value in global variable and can fetch

Comment: @Ashley I am able to get the value but not abe to set the value

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800685/variable-value-is-not-appending-in-h2-element & http://jsfiddle.net/pc2tx1us/4/

Comment: @Ashley Sorry to say but that would not work I need to set value for dropdown which I am not able to do

Comment: @Ashley Its working with static id $('#asdf').val($('#asdf  option').eq(3).val()); but if I am trying to use dynamic ID its not working Could you suggest how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Use find() [http://api.jquery.com/find] to find the dynamically created selector and set selected attribute.